# How do you do change feed monitoring in a mongo API Cosmos DB now change feed processing has been disabled and Azure functions dont exist

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Hey we have been using the change feed processor library for 6 months with a Cosmos DB and Mongo API  but now when we try and connect to the change processor library we get a Document Exception and the mesage

```
Sql api is not supported for this database account
```

The nuget we are using is 
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.ChangeFeedProcessor v2.2.7

The last time we created the new database was about 3 weeks ago and its still working but every new mongo api cosmos we create throws this error.

If this has been retrospectivly removed without documentation or warning is there any other way to listen to changes in the database without writing my own monitoring software.

The documentation has been changed and now says it doesnt support it but i have a working DB that says it does.

Answer (score 0):

So the feature wasnt really supported and has been disabled for new databases but there is a new change feed processor lib for mongo api enabled cosmos due out in Spetember.

Marking as answered as not sure there is a workaround available until the lib is out